# [schema.sql]Incorrect syntax near ','. Expecting ID, QUOTED_ID, STRING, or TEXT_LEX

Tags: python, sql

I got a syntax error in schema.sql.
The error message is as below:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.  Expecting ID, QUOTED_ID, STRING, or TEXT_LEX.

Here is my code:

```
drop table if exists entries;
create table entries 
(
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    title text not null,
    text text not null
);
```

I found a similar issue in Stackoverflow.com, and refactored my re sqlfile.

Here is the difference.

```
drop table if exists entries;

create table entries 
(
     id integer primary key autoincrement,
     title text not null,
-    text text not null
+    'text' text not null
);
```

However, the error has been not resolved, and this error message is still displayed.

########### Updated

I create schema.sql as I refer this page: https://github.com/mjhea0/flaskr-tdd

> Create a new file called schema.sql and add the following code:

```
drop table if exists entries;
create table entries (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  title text not null,
  text text not null
);
```

> This will set up a single table with three fields - "id", "title", and "text". SQLite will be used for our RDMS since it's built in to the standard Python library and requires no configuration.

Comment: I don't see a database tagged to this question. which database are you using ?

Comment: How are you executing this file? Is this for a sqlite database? Please try to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I updated my quetion I posted.

Comment: It looks like you've just reproduced the exact `schema.sql` file that you'd already included. Ideally you want to try to compose a question that is fully self-contained so that others may copy and paste your code and run it and encounter the error that you are experiencing, rather than provide links to entire github repos.

Comment: I may get a way to correct my mistake. sqlfile should be created not by executing   "touch" command, but by typing on console as bellow:

Comment: gkz@localhost ~$ sqlite3 schema.sql
SQLite version 3.27.2 2019-02-25 16:06:06
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> drop table if exists entries;
sqlite> create table entries ( id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, 'text' text not null );
sqlite> .schema entries
CREATE TABLE entries ( id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, 'text' text not null );
sqlite> 
sqlite> \q
   ...> 
Error: unrecognized token: "\"
gkz@localhost ~ $

Answer (score -1):

```
drop table if exists entries;
create table entries 
(
    id Integer primary key identity,
    title text not null,
    text text not null
);
```

Comment: Thx for your quick reply.  I found I should not touch sqlfile but execute sqlcommand as bellow: https://github.com/mjhea0/flaskr-tdd/issues/50